# Blazor - parent functions runs when clicking child

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Blazor Page:

```
@inject IImageService ImageService
@using Design_A_Bear.Models
@using Design_A_Bear.Services


<div class="border-top pt-2 me-5 rounded" @onclick="Redirect" >
        <div style="width:200px;height:250px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
            <img src="@ImageService.ConvertBase64ToImage(Item.ImgBase64)" alt="@Item.Name image" class="" style="width:200px;height:200px;" />
        </div>
    <div class="bg-secondary rounded-bottom p-3 position-relative">
        <hr class="text-light mb-2"/>
        <h5 class="fw-bold text-light">@Item.Name</h5>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-3">
            <p class="mt-2 text-secondary fw-bold text-light">@String.Format("{0:C}", @Item.Price) </p>
            <button @onclick="Redirect2" class="btn btn-primary fw-bold rounded text-light z-3"><i class="bi bi-cart-plus-fill"></i> Add to Basket</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    @hello
</div>
```

Within this page i have given the parent div and the button a separate function. But when i click thew button only the `Redirect` functions runs and not the `Redirect2`  function. I know that its because its the parent div but is there a way to run the button function and not the div when clicking the button? As i want two seperate redirects. When a user clicks the button it should add the item into the basket but if the user clicks anywhere else on the card it will redirect them to the product page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button has to stop with propagating the event:

```
 <button @onclick:stopPropagation="@true" @onclick="Redirect2">Button </button>
```